# Paginate Arrays PHP

Tags: php, pagination

I am stumped after looking, I have 3 arrays returning 200 results each - I want to paginate the results (50 per page) so I can use infinite scroll on them... can anyone offer any insight?

Here are

```
$facebookfeed = json_decode($fbfeed, true);
$twitterfeed = json_decode($twfeed, true);
$instagramfeed = json_decode($igfeed, true);
```

then I would imagine it would go something like

```
// Twitter
          $i = 0;
          foreach ($twitterfeed as $value) {
            $text = $value['text'];
            echo '<li class="element twitter">';
            echo '<p>' . $text . '</p>';
            echo '</li>';
            if($i > 50){break;}
            };
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yeah i have tried a bunch of pagination tutorials but they always refer to MYSQL, I am working with social api pulls

Answer (score 0):

use `array_merge()` to merge the arrays?

you can use `sort()` if you need to sort the different arrays into each other after merging.